# Insert additional rows into array and input in to database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance if anyone can help!

I have an array of data displayed in a table, I can edit the data and then update my database with the edited data.

```
<input type='button' value='new row' id='save' onClick="addRow()"/>
<table id='mech_table'>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type='text' size='30' name='value_total'id='mech_value_total' value='£0.00' readonly='readonly'/></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type='text' size='30' name='value_claim' id='mech_claim_total' value='£<?php echo $row_MECHT['mech_total']; ?>' readonly='readonly'/></td>
</tr><tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>%</th>
<th>Claim</th>
</tr>
<?php while ($MECH = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<form name='form_update' method='post' action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $MECH['id']; ?><input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='<?php echo $MECH['id'];?>' /></td>
<td class='description_row'><input type='text' size='70' name='description[]' value='<?php echo $MECH['description'];?>' /></td>
<td class='value_row'><input class='mech_value_total' type='text' size='30' name='value[]' value='<?php echo $MECH['value'];?>' /></td>
<td class='percent_row'><input class='percent' type='text' size='10' name='percentclaim[]' value='<?php echo $MECH['percentclaim'];?>' /></td>
<td class='claim_row'><input class='mech_claim_total' type='text' size='30' name='claim[]' value='<?php echo $MECH['claim'] ?>' readonly='readonly'/></td>
</tr>
<?php  ++$ia;
}
?>  
</table>
<input type='submit' value='save' id='save' /><br /><br /><br />
</form>


$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

$size = count($_POST['id']);
$i = 0;
while($i<$size){
$description= $_POST['description'][$i];
$value= $_POST['value'][$i];
$percentclaim= $_POST['percentclaim'][$i];
$claim= $_POST['claim'][$i];
$id = $_POST['id'][$i];
$query = "INSERT INTO applicationmech 
                  SET id='$id', 
                      description='$description', 
                      value='$value', 
                      percentclaim='$percentclaim', 
                      claim='$claim' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE description='$description', 
                      value='$value', 
                      percentclaim='$percentclaim', 
                      claim='$claim'";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
$updateGoTo = "preditvaluation.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
++$i;
}
```

I have created a simple button with javascript which allows me to add additional rows to my table.

```
function addRow() {  

$('#mech_table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" /></td><td class="description_row"><input type="text" size="70" name="description[]" value="" /></td><td class="value_row"><input class="mech_value_total" type="text" size="30" name="value[]" value="" /></td><td class="percent_row"><input class="percent" type="text" size="10" name="percentclaim[]" value="" /></td><td class="claim_row"><input class="mech_claim_total" type="text" size="30" name="claim[]" value="" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>');

}
```

My problem is, when I click the update button, the data in my new rows does not save.

I have been trying many different methods and how to get this to work but failed every time.

Comment: no error message, all existing rows update fine but new rows will not insert. Even if I change code to only INSERT, the additional row(s) are ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The data in your new rows will not have an id value, so the database will be unable to update the row in an UPDATE operation. You need the server side code to do something like:

```
$newids = array();

if (!empty($row->id)) {
    $DB->update('tablename', $data);
} else {
    $newid = $DB->insert('tablename', $data);
    $newids[] = $newid;
}

// Now send the new ids back to the browser so that they can be put into those rows 
// and an update operation will be performed next time
echo json_encode($ids);
```

On the browser end, something like:

```
var ids = jQuery.parseJSON(dataFromAjax);
var inputsNeedingIds = $('input:inputclass').filter(
    function() { 
        return ($(this).val() == "") && ($(this).attr('name') == 'id[]'); });
inputsNeedingIds.each(
    function(i) {
        this.id.value = ids[i];});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I just can get it to work! I'm still quite new at this and don’t quite understand what to do.

I’ve also tried several other things since yesterday but still nothing works, it seems that when the INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bit runs it ignores the added row?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing problematic here is that DOM is not updated properly with your addition of new form elements supplemented by addRow() function. The form is subbmitted with the form elements that was being displayed at the start.

This is possible only when you use Ajax Submission. Easiest way would be http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm its very easy to integrate. give it a try! ;)

If form_update is your form's ID then code would be

```
$('#form_update').ajaxForm({
        target:        '#result-sub',   
        success:       function(){
            $('#result-sub').show();
            $('#form_update').hide();
    }
});
```

Add a div or something with id 'result-sub' to give back the response of insertion.